# RenderTargetBitmap getting error insufficient memory

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, render

I am getting insufficient memory exception when i am trying to render a image(10000 X 10000) resolution with canvas(10000 X 10000) resolution.

```
bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)width, (int(height),graphics.DpiX,graphics.DpiY,PixelFormats.Default)bmp.Render(vs);

    dc.PushTransform(new TranslateTransform(difX + left - horizontalScale, difY + top - verticalScale));
                    dc.PushTransform(new ScaleTransform(1, 1));

                    // Ask canvas to draw overlays
                    drawingCanvas.Draw(dc);

                    // Restore old actual scale.
                    drawingCanvas.ActualScale = oldActualScale;

                    // Restore clip
                    drawingCanvas.RefreshClip();

                    dc.Pop();
                    dc.Pop();
                    dc.Pop();

                    dc.Close();
                    width = (Utilityhelper.GetDIPIndependentHorizontal(rect.Width));
                    height = (Utilityhelper.GetDIPIndependentVertical(rect.Height));

                    bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)width, (int)(height), Utilityhelper.graphics.DpiX, Utilityhelper.graphics.DpiY, PixelFormats.Default);
                    if (bmp != null)
                    {
                        bmp.Render(vs);
                    }
```

Comment: Microsoft guys call `7000x7000` canvas [huge](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c5e31d70-08d1-4402-8016-0a0b7af49b04/rendertargetbitmaprender-throws-outofmemoryexception-when-rendering-large-visuals?forum=wpf). You have to install more memory or change approach, because the one you are using needs more memory.

Comment: ya so can you suggest me what should i need to use to implement this kind of functioality...

Comment: What kind of functionality? I have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: i need to merge image with draw element on canvase.. eg i need to draw rectangle on image so here i am using RenderTargetBitmap approuch and after that i save that image  RenderTargetBitmap that code working fine with normal resolution image

Comment: are you understanding ?

Comment: You can't edit *normal* and *large* (huge?) images similarly. With large images there are always memory-related problems. Making `x64` application and installing more memory can solve them, so that you can continue using *simple* `RenderTargetBitmap` approach. Easiest you can do is handle exception and say user "Sorry, image is too big, use some other software" (Photoshop?). Another option is to search for a library which will allow to work with huge images without loading them completely (and I don't know such, sorry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done with using this.... DecodePixelWidth & DecodePixelHeight  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelwidth(v=vs.110).aspx